What mode is the SPI used in the below image?

Working on some SPI bit banging communication, not able to make the SPI communicate.
Primarily need to understand what mode the SPI is in.   What are the significance of delay between different SPI mode while doing bit banging mode.
Below provided the code. I use 64MHz internal RC oscillator.
    uint8_t SPI_TransferReceiver_Byte(uint8_t dataTX) {

    uint8_t dataRX = 0;

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Set the data bit on the output
        if (dataTX & (1 << i)) 
        {
            ADC_DIN_SetHigh();
        }
        else 
        {
            ADC_DIN_SetLow();
        }

        // Pulse the clock high
        ADC_SCL_SetHigh();
        
        //Delay ?
        
        // Read the input data while the clock is high
        if (ADC_DOUT_GetValue()) {
            dataRX |= 1 << i;
        }

        // Pulse the clock low
        ADC_SCL_SetLow();
        
        //Delay ?
    }

    return dataRX;
}


It is necessary to meet the minimum timing requirements specified in Table 2 of the datasheet.
For example, when you are doing a data write (Figure 4), you need to make sure the DIN input data is stable at least 30ns before the rising edge of the clock signal (SCLK).  If your processor is running at 64MHz, its internal clock period is about 16ns.  This means you need to wait at least 2 processor cycles between when you drive DIN and when you drive SCLK high.  This is timing parameter \$t_9\$.
You must keep DIN stable for at least 25ns (\$t_{10}\$) after the SCLK rising edge.

Regarding the question about SPI mode, the AD7798 uses SPI data and clock timing corresponding to CPOL=1 and CPHA=1.

Your C code seems to do a write and a read at the same time.  This is unexpected.  It might be better to perform these operations in 2 separate functions (one for Write and the other for Read).
